# How can I combine multiple selected objects into a single mesh in Blender while retaining each object's animation data?

Tags: animation, export, .fbx

I want to combine multiple selected objects into a single mesh in Blender, while preserving the individual animation of each object. Essentially, I want to create a new object that contains the combined mesh data of the selected objects, but without losing the animation information that is unique to each object. What is the best way to accomplish[image]

Comment: if you have animated your objects with shape keys - this would work. If you animated "normal values" like location/rotation -> this cannot work because there is only one animation value per object AFAIK